# Build Vue Component with external Libraries for usage in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I have a component, which uses some filter and external added components. I will include this component in a static website. I build my component as lib, but it does not include the filters.

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name eventsFeed --inline-vue",
```

my main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueCurrencyFilter from 'vue-currency-filter';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(require("vue-moment"));
Vue.use(VueCurrencyFilter,
{
  symbol : '€',
  thousandsSeparator: '.',
  fractionCount: 2,
  fractionSeparator: ',',
  symbolPosition: 'end',
  symbolSpacing: true
});

export default {
  components: {
    App,
  },
}
```

Which setup is wrong or which command is missing to include all dependencies in the build files?

Thanks!